# Isomorphism: $F = \mathbb{Z}_{5}(\alpha)$, $\alpha^2 +2 =0$, and $F'= \mathbb{Z}_{5}(\beta)$, $\beta ^2 + \beta + 1 = 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F = \mathbb{Z}_{5}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha^2 +2 =0$, and let $F'= \mathbb{Z}_{5}(\beta)$, where $\beta ^2 + \beta + 1 = 0$.
Exhibit the isomorphism between $F$ and $F'$.

Honestly, I don't know how to solve this problem. I tried to do it by finding roots, which are $\alpha = \pm \sqrt{2}i$ and $\beta = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}$

Please help me to solve this provlem. Thank you!

Comment: All of the elements in $F$ are in the form of $c\alpha+d$, so multiplying two elements yields: $$(c\alpha+d)(e\alpha+f)=c\alpha^2+(cf+de)\alpha+df=(cf+de)\alpha+df+3c$$ Similarly, mutliplying two elements in $F'$ yields: $$(c\beta+d)(e\beta+f)=c\beta^2+(cf+de)\beta+df=(cf+de+4c)\beta+df+4c$$ I don't know if that helps, but maybe you understand the fields better now?

Comment: I would take your first field, and its $25$ elements, and among these elements, I would look for one that was a root of $X^2+X+1$. Or do the reverse: look for a square root of $3$ in $\Bbb Z_5[\beta]/(\beta^2+\beta+1)$. You may find that the slick way of performing such a search is to find a primitive element (one of order $24$) and write out all its powers. Tedious, but you’ll learn a lot in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\alpha^2 = 3$, thus $\alpha^4 = 3^2 = 4$, and so $\alpha^8 = 4^2 = 1$. So the order of $\alpha$ is 8.

Now $(\alpha + 1)^2 = \alpha^2 + 2\alpha + 1 = 3 + 2\alpha + 1 = 2\alpha + 4$, and consequently:

$(\alpha + 1)^3 = (\alpha + 1)(2\alpha + 4) = 2\alpha^2 + 4\alpha + 2\alpha + 4 = 2(3) + 4 + \alpha = \alpha$.

This shows that the order of $\alpha + 1$ must be $24$ (do you see why it cannot be a multiple of $3$ less than $24$? Since we already know the order is not $2$, that leaves only $4$ and $8$- but:

$(\alpha + 1)^8 = (\alpha + 1)^6(\alpha + 1)^2 = \alpha^2(\alpha + 1)^2 = 3(2\alpha + 4) = \alpha + 2 \neq 1$).

So $(\Bbb Z_5(\alpha))^{\ast}$ is generated by $(\alpha + 1)$.

On the other hand we have $\beta^3 = \beta(\beta^2) = \beta(4\beta + 4) = 4\beta^2 + 4\beta = 4(4\beta + 4) + 4\beta$

$= \beta + 1 + 4\beta = 1$.

Since $3 = \dfrac{24}{8} = \dfrac{24}{\gcd(8,24)}$, it seems reasonable that we might hope $(\alpha + 1)^8 = \alpha + 2$ is a root of $x^2 + x + 1$.

I leave it you to show this is indeed the case, and then define the sought-after isomorphism.